# Hungerford and the Well Ordering Principle

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

In Hungerford's Algebra, he states that each of the following is a well ordering of $\mathbb Z$:

(i) $0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,...,n,-n,...$

(ii) $0,1,3,5,7,...,2,4,6,8,...,-1,-2,-3,-4,...$

(iii) $0,3,4,5,6,...,-1,-2,-3,-4,...,1,2$

He also says later on that the element $0$ is the least element in all three orderings. I believe I understand the definitions and am still greatly confused on his explanations for these examples.

Comment: What's your question, exactly?

Comment: Is it obvious to you what he is saying here?

Comment: What's to explain?  What are you confused about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just examples.

The "normal" order of the integers are $....,-3 ,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,....$ but that's not a well ordering because not every subset has a least element.

We can make a well ordering of a countable set just be arbitrarily picking one element after another.  Ex.  $17, -5, 8, 15,37, -92,0, 39,etc.$ (in this case $17$ is the least integer).

However a subtle thing is that if because every subset has a least element it does *not* follow that every subset has greatest element (nor does it mean every infinite subset doesn't). Nor does it mean that because for any $y$ we can't have *infinitely* many $x < y$.  In fact it doesn't mean we can't have uncountably many $x < y$.

So the first example shows how you can put all integers into an order so that there is always a least element and but every element has an indexed position.

The second example shows that every subset has a least element, but you *can* have infinitely many elements below an element.

And the third example shows you can do that infinitely many such infinite gaps.

Answer (score 0):

Each of these 3 sequences is defining a new ordering on the integers, unrelated to the usual ordering.  The elements are listed so that smaller (in the new ordering) elements come before larger elements.  So, for example, in the first sequence, $0 \prec 1 \prec  -1 \prec  2 \prec  -2 \prec  \ldots$  (I am using the curly $\prec$ rather than the usual < to emphasize that it's not the usual ordering).  0 is the least element in all 3 orderings because it is listed first in all 3 orderings.